# How to move children of a div with no event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I am currently making a game where blocks fall and you have to avoid them. I have some jQuery code that appends blocks to a `div`called *game*.

I am having trouble selecting every single `div` spawned and making them move down with no clicking. [Here is the GitHub link](https://github.com/FlipFloop/Color-Drop) and here an [example](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/FlipFloop/Color-Drop/blob/master/index.html)

Here is the jQuery code (part of it)

```
function spawn_block(){

$spawned_block = $("<div class='block'></div>")
$game.append($spawned_block); //add div with class block to #game div

var left=getRandomInt(0, $game.width()-$spawned_block.width()); //gets a random value from left of screen where div can appear
var top=getRandomInt(0, $game.height()-$spawned_block.height()); //not useful unless you don't want the div to appear at the top
//adds a random position and color to spawned_block

$spawned_block.css({
    "left": left,
    "background-color": getRandomColor()
});
//if you want a random position from top add "top" : top,
};
```

---

```
    if($spawned_block.position.top < $game.position.top + $game.height ) {
        $spawned_block.css("top", "+=25px");
    }
```

This last piece of code is what I added at the end of the function, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what is happening to you but is only the most recently added `div` moving down? Perhaps it would help if you did something like:

```
$("#game .block").each(function(index){
    if($(this).position.top < $game.position.top + $game.height ) {
        $(this).css("top", "+=25px");
    }
});
```

This goes through every single `.block` within the element of the id `#game` and runs your `if` statement on it.

The other thing that might be your problem (I'm afraid your question isn't clear enough for me to tell) is that you're only running the function to move everything down when an event happens (like a click or a block being added). Perhaps something like this might work for you:

```
function anim() {
    $("#game .block").each(function(index){
        if($(this).position.top < $game.position.top + $game.height ) {
            $(this).css("top", "+=25px");
        }
    });
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

This tells the browser (through the line `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);`) to, on the next frame, run the function `anim()` which moves the blocks down. You can read more about `requestAnimationFrame()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your help, however it still doesn't work for me! :( Still, big thx for making me see what is my basic error

Comment: @FlipFloop If you could update your question or your GitHub with the most recent version of your code, I can revise my answer to better help you.